# Audio visualization with QMediaPlayer

Tags: qt, audio, visualization

I am playing audio with the [QMediaPlayer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html) and want to visualize the audio levels (for example like in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1Y_AZ8fJD0&list=UUJ6td3C9QlPO9O_J5dF4ZzA)).
I already found a example from the Qt 4 documentation but they were manually generating the signal and I found no way to get the audio output buffer with the QMediaPlayer.
How should I solve this problem / are there other audio librarys (crossplatform) that can accomplish this?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at [`QAudioProbe`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaudioprobe.html).

> The QAudioProbe class allows you to monitor audio being played or recorded.

As the `QMediaPlayer` is a subclass of `QMediaObject`, you attach the `QAudioProbe` to the `QMediaPlayer` with `bool QAudioProbe::setSource(QMediaObject* source)`, then connect to the `void QAudioProbe::audioBufferProbed(const QAudioBuffer& buffer)` signal. The documentation provides an example.

In the slot for the `audioBufferProbed` signal you can process the raw audio data to calculate volume, for example by computing the [RMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of the sample. Have a look at this [article on calculating the RMS efficiently](http://www.embedded.com/design/configurable-systems/4006520/Improve-your-root-mean-calculations).

To display the volume you could use [`QProgressBar`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprogressbar.html), but you may get better performance using the [Qt Widgets for Technical Applications](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) library which can also work on a logarithmic scale which will be needed for a volume display.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was searching.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar and used the audioBufferProbed signal to capture the buffer, but the problem is this signal gets emitted very soon i.e the difference between the two emission is nearly 10ms. Is there a way to control the emission of this signal ? Because of this the fft processing which is being done in the slot gets screwed up. Am i doing this the right way ?

Comment: @astre I don't think there is any way to control the signal rate. You could create a proxy class that would do this to batch several signals together. Alternatively, you may want to do the FFT in another thread, for example use [`QtConcurrent::run`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run) to run the FFT and use a [`QFutureWatcher`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html) in the GUI to get the results to display them.