# Qt - Using QAudioProbe with QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

I am trying to use the `QAudioProbe` class with `QMediaPlayer` but I can't seem to get it working. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339741/audio-visualization-with-qmediaplayer), I'm using it to create an audio visualizer.  I had the following:

```
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer;
QAudioProbe* probe = new QAudioProbe;

// note: processBuffer() is a custom slot
connect(probe, SIGNAL(audioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)),
        this, SLOT(processBuffer(QAudioBuffer)));

if(!probe->setSource(player))
    cout << "Source for AudioProbe not set!" << endl;
```

Whenever I tried to set `player` as the source for `probe`, it returned `false`.

Next, I tried setting the media for `player` *before* setting it as the source for `probe`.

```
player->setMedia(...);

if(!probe->setSource(player))
    cout << "Source for AudioProbe not set!" << endl;

player->play();
```

Still returns false. I've been looking online for a while now but no luck. Any suggestions to get this working?

Suggestions for other methods of receiving data from `QMediaPlayer` are also welcomed. However, I would prefer to use Qt classes.

Comment: which Qt version and which platform are you using? this feature seems to be available only for specific platforms according to http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.user/10973

Comment: @m.s. I'm using Qt 5.4.0 and OSx. According to the link you gave me, OSx is not supported by `QAudioProbe`. I wish the supported platforms for a class were written in plain sight in the documentation.

Comment: *Copied from answer by Simon Drouin*: The complete list of supported/unsupported features of QtMultimedia, by platform, can be found [here](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.5.0_Multimedia_Backends). Unfortunately, a lot of features don't work in OSX.

Comment: Did you ever solves this? I am having the same issue (OSX, etc). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096322/generating-a-waveform-from-an-audio-or-video-file

Comment: @TOMATO No. OSx doesn't support `QAudioProbe`. Take a look at the [link](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.5.0_Multimedia_Backends) provided by Bowdzone.

Comment: @JeffersonSteelflex – thanks. Yes, I wasted a day. Thanks Qt documentation. .  .