# Get QAudioBuffer from QMediaPlayer

Tags: qt, audio, qmediaplayer

I want to build an audio visualizer using `QMediaPlayer`. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339741/audio-visualization-with-qmediaplayer) but `QAudioProbe` would not allow me to set `QMediaPlayer` as its source. I believe it may not be supported on OSX.

I have also found [this](http://doc.qt.io/QtDataVisualization/qtdatavisualization-audiolevels-example.html) but I'm not sure how to make it work with `QMediaPlayer` as that example uses a `QIODevice`.

Is there another way to getting `QAudioBuffer` from a `QMediaPlayer` without using `QAudioProbe`? If not, what is another approach to getting data from `QMediaPlayer` in order to build a visualizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Multimedia_Backends), AV Foundation backend has support neither for Audio probe, nor for Stream source. You are out of luck. You need to decode audio with some other library, for example [libmpg123](http://www.mpg123.de/api/) or [libogg](http://xiph.org/vorbis/), depending on the format. Then you can play it with [OpenAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAL).